# Space between buttons in sap.m.Dialog buttons aggregation

Tags: sapui5

I am working on sap.m.Dialog control with 3 buttons and i need to show button "A" on the left side, button "B" in the middle and button "C" on the right side.

Please refer below code and screenshot

[image]

**Controller.js**

```
var oDialog = new Dialog({
    title: "Dialog",
    type: 'Message',
    content: new Text({ text: "" }),
    buttons : [
        new sap.m.Button({
            text: "A"
        }),
        new sap.m.Button({
            text: "B"
        }),
        new sap.m.Button({
            text: "C"
        })
    ],
    afterClose: function() {
        oDialog.destroy();
    }
});
oDialog.open();
```

**My workaround**:

```
var oDialog = new Dialog({
    title: "Dialog",
    type: 'Message',
    content: new Text({ text: "" }),
    buttons : [
        new sap.m.Button({
            text: "A"
        }),
        // below added few dummy buttons to show space like effect at UI
        new sap.m.Button({text: "", visible:true, enabled:false}),
        new sap.m.Button({text: "", visible:true, enabled:false}),
        new sap.m.Button({
            text: "B"
        }),
        // below added few dummy buttons to show space like effect at UI
        new sap.m.Button({text: "", visible:true, enabled:false}),
        new sap.m.Button({text: "", visible:true, enabled:false}),
        new sap.m.Button({
            text : "C"
        })
    ],
    afterClose: function() {
        oDialog.destroy();
    }
});
oDialog.open();
```

***How it looks after adding empty buttons***
[image]

i have added button with blank text, somehow i have achieved to show spaces in between buttons, *but is this a right way to add space like effect at UI ? or is there any proper way to satisfy my requirement ?*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74798601/5846045. Works also on mobile

Answer (score 1):

As of UI5 1.110, `sap.m.Dialog` comes with the new `footer` aggregation ([commit `cc55b10`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/cc55b10c9df3682e88a6273714db1d76a8d2290d)) which awaits an instance of `sap.m.Toolbar`. There, you can add anything you want such as the three `<Button>`s and `<ToolbarSpacer>`s in between.

Run this snippet to see the result:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], async (XMLView) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      displayBlock="true"
      height="100%"
    >
      <App>
        <dependents>
          <Dialog id="myDialog"
            initialFocus="okButton"
            title="Dialog"
            draggable="true"
            resizable="true"
          >
            <footer>
              <Toolbar>
                <Button text="Buton A" />
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <Button text="Buton B" />
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <Button text="Buton C" />
              </Toolbar>
            </footer>
          </Dialog>
        </dependents>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    afterRendering: function () {
      this.byId("myDialog").open();
    }
  });
  control.placeAt("content");
})
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would work with custom css. Insert in your manifest.json a css file,

```
...
  "sap.ui5": {
    ... 
    "resources": {
      "css": [{
        "uri": "css/style.css"
      }]
    }
  }
```

Create style.css within the uri css/style.css. Give in your view the buttons ids. Target within the stlye.css the buttons with #. Align the buttons within the style.css.

Comment: hi @n01dea, thank you for your reply, is there any workaround without applying css and adding margin class to button

Comment: Perhaps flex box helps: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.FlexBoxBasicAlignment/preview. Please check the center demos out. Then just add left and right margins to the button in the center

Comment: i tried adding sap.m.FlexBox control too, but end up getting uncaught error **Uncaught Error: "Element sap.m.FlexBox#__box0" is not valid for aggregation "buttons" of Element sap.m.Dialog#__dialog0**
`buttons : [
  new sap.m.FlexBox({
  items:[ 
 new sap.m.Button({
  text: "A"
 }),
 new sap.m.Button({
  text: "B"
 }),
 new sap.m.Button({
  text : "C"
 })
  ]
 })
]`

Comment: Sorry, missed that dialog just takes the aggregation buttons for the footer. Maybe new sap.m.Button({text: "B"}).addStyleClass("sapUiLargeMarginBeginEnd") works out

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
An alternative way would be to place a Bar control in the content aggregation of the dialog.

```
var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
            title: "Dialog",
            type: 'Message',
            content: 
                new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout({
                    width:"100%",
                    content: [
                        new sap.m.Text({
                        text: 'One of the keys to success is creating realistic goals that can be achieved in a reasonable amount of time.'                    
                        }).addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMargin"),
                        new sap.m.Bar({
                            design: "Footer",
                            contentLeft:  new sap.m.Button({ text: "Button A"}),
                            contentMiddle:  new sap.m.Button({ text: "Button B"}),
                            contentRight:  new sap.m.Button({ text: "Button C"})
                        })
                    ]
                }),
            afterClose: function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            }
        });
        dialog.addStyleClass("sapUiNoContentPadding ");
```

Original Answer:

You can assign widths in percentages to responsively handle it. Since you are using 3 buttons you can assign a width of about 30% to each of the buttons. This may cause some issues on mobile devices because of the dynamically added margins which can be removed with the standard "sapUiNoMarginBegin" & "sapUiNoMarginEnd" classes.

Code Snippet:

```
buttons : [
                new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Button A",
                    width:"30%"
                }).addStyleClass("sapUiNoMarginEnd").addStyleClass("sapUiNoMarginBegin"),
                new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Button B",
                    width:"30%"
                }).addStyleClass("sapUiNoMarginEnd").addStyleClass("sapUiNoMarginBegin"),
                new sap.m.Button({
                    text : "Button C",
                    width:"30%"
                }).addStyleClass("sapUiNoMarginEnd").addStyleClass("sapUiNoMarginBegin")
            ],
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't add any spaces between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting button "A" in aggregation `beginButton`, button "B" in aggregation `buttons` and button "C" in aggregation `endButton`.

Comment: hi @amiramw, i tried your workaround but i found that you can use beginButton, endButton and buttons aggregation in dialog at the same time but buttons aggregation overrides beginButton and endButton, so no point of using them.

Answer (score 0):

@Prashob

Use Flexbox control as below:

```
<FlexBox height="100px" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center">
                <items>
                    <Button text="Submit" type="Emphasized" width="300px" press="submitDetails"/>
                </items>
            </FlexBox>
```

You need to change the justifyContent property according to where you need the button.
For three buttons you will require 3 flexbox which will contain each button. Maybe to put them side to side you can use HBOX control.

```
              <HBox>
                    <items>
                        <FlexBox id="fb1" height="100px" alignItems="Center" width="400px" justifyContent="SpaceAround">
                            <items>
                                <Button id="b1" text="Start" width="200px"/>
                            </items>
                        </FlexBox>
                        <FlexBox id="fb2" justifyContent="Center" height="100px" alignItems="Center" width="400px">
                            <items>
                                <Button id="b2" text="Center" width="200px"/>
                            </items>
                        </FlexBox>
                        <FlexBox id="fb3" justifyContent="End" height="100px" width="400px" alignItems="Center">
                            <items>
                                <Button id="b3" text="End" width="200px"/>
                            </items>
                        </FlexBox>
                    </items>
                </HBox>
```

Check the output of above code as below:
[image: output]

You can change the justifyContent property accordingly and the width of button and flexboxes to get the desired result.

Comment: hi @loki, thank you for your reply, but i cannot use FlexBox or HBox as a buttons aggregation for dialog. Even if i use it, i will end up getting error on screen, because sap.m.Button is the only control that can be used in buttons aggregation for sap.m.Dialog.

Comment: @Prashob       Oh i didnot see the sap.m.Dialog. I haven't used the Dialog control yet, I am also new to SAPUI5. If i find something I would post it again.

Comment: @Prashob No aggregation for buttons this is so frustrating xD They had the leftButton and RightButton association but its deprecated now.